# Is there a way of getting notifications when a terraform run fail or succede

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a scenario where i need a notification of each resource terraform creates successfully and also it should give me notification if terraform fails.

one way of doing it could be having a AWS SNS which push on topic with each successful resource creation but here i cant notify if a resource creation fails

so if you have some suggestions please do share
Thanks !!

Comment: you can use slack for notification using curl call

Comment: I'm confused what you want here. Terraform is synchronous and shouldn't really be running unattended and even if you were then you'd want your orchestrator to handle this instead of Terraform. Can you explain more fully what you're trying to do here?

Comment: yes correct it should not be left unattended but what if we have to? is it possible to make it get monitored during it's execution? my terraform scripts are getting executed as part of AWS Instance's User Data and i'm sending it's logs to CloudWatch but it would be better if there's a way i could get notifications only when resource creation complete's or fails

Comment: What are you doing that has a user data script execute Terraform? This feels like a terrible idea without more context.

Comment: with a cloudformation template i'm creating a EC2 instance and inside this EC2 instance's userdata i'm executing terraform. Terraform configuration files are already stored in AMI that spins the Ec2. Now that i have userdata logs in cloudwatch is there a way to get notified on success/fail of terraform

Comment: I suggest you just use a normal CI/CD tool that give you notifications on successful pipeline execution or failure. Perhaps not a "direct" answer to your question, but that's what I would personally do.